# Return Json as a variable

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-4

If I return the following from an MVC action:

```
return Json(new { hello="world" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Then I get something like the following...

```
{hello: "world"}
```

How can I make it return something like:

```
var myObj = {hello: "world"};
```

This would mean I didn't need to use Ajax to make the request. I could just reference the JSON using script tags.

Comment: With String Concatenation, and return String

Comment: How would one incorporate that with the existing JsonResult?

Comment: Are you asking how to write ASP.NET program that will generate a JavaScript program consisting of nothing except an object literal assignment to a variable?

Comment: @CodeCaster So I can do a simple... '<script type="text/javascript" src="~/myScript.aspx"></script>' instead of an Ajax request. This was in the question.

Comment: @Quentin Perhaps you should ask the MVC team why they created an action result that returns a JavaScript program consisting of nothing except an object literal.

Comment: @IanWarburton — No need to ask them. JSON is a very widely used [standard data format](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt) that uses the same syntax as JavaScript object literals.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't use JsonResult. I did this...

```
return string.Format("var myObj = {0};", new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(myObj));
```